# Unable to automate the click of a button in Selenium with Python

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I am trying to automate the log in process to WebAdvisor. I have tried to select the "Log In" button by calling different elements. Each attempt so far has been unsuccessful.

My current code:

`path = '.../chromedriver`

`driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)`

`url = 'https://webadvisor.barry.edu/`

`driver.get(url)`

The below have been unsuccessful.

`driver.find_element_by_id('acctLogin').click()`

`driver.find_element_by_name('Log In').click()`

`driver.find_element_by_link_text("Log In").click()`

This is the section of the code related to the button I am trying to click on in the WebAdvisor website:

[image: Html code of WebAdvisor]

The expected result is the log in page. At the moment it does not change page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your xpath is wrong, Please find below solution.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("https://webadvisor.barry.edu/")


element=WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//li[@id='acctLogin']//span[@class='label'][contains(text(),'Log In')]")))
element.click()
element0=WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='USER_NAME']")))
element0.send_keys("Test123")
```

Comment: Thanks Rock! It works! Out of curiosity I tested it with 1 second and it still works. I tested it without the WebDriverWait method and it doesn't work. Why is the method WebDriverWait necessary?

Answer (score 1):

Induce [WebDriverWait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) And `element_to_be_clickable`() And following locator startegy.

**Xpath**:

```
driver=webdriver.Chrome(path)
driver.get("https://webadvisor.barry.edu/")
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//li[@id='acctLogin']/a[./span[contains(.,'Log In')]]"))).click()
```

**CSS Selector:**

```
driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://webadvisor.barry.edu/")
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#acctLogin >a"))).click()
```

You need to import following libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

**Browser Snapshot:**

[image]